# How can I extend a terraform module written by third party easily?

Tags: terraform

Here is a module that create a sns topic for RDS events

```
module "rds_event_sns" {
  source = "../../../../common/sns/topic"
  name = "${var.lambda_filename}-rds-event"
}
```

And here is the content of the `main.tf` in `common/sns/topic`

```
terraform {
  required_version = "0.11.7"
}

variable "name" {}

variable "publishers" {
  type = "list"
}


resource "aws_sns_topic" "topic_simple" {
  name = "canva-${var.queue_prefix}${var.name}"
}
```

How I want to be able to set `lambda_failure_feedback_role_arn` and `lambda_failure_feedback_role_arn` on the sns topic. It does not look like the resource `topic_simple` is accepting these properties.

Can I simply pass these properties to `topic_simple` without making changes to `common/sns/topic`? e.g.

```
module "rds_event_sns" {
  source = "../../../../common/sns/topic"
  name = "${var.lambda_filename}-rds-event"
  lambda_failure_feedback_role_arn: "arn:aws:iam::147857925614:role/SNSFailureFeedback"
  lambda_success_feedback_role_arn: "arn:aws:iam::147857925614:role/SNSSuccessFeedback"
}
```

If it is not how terraform works, what is a good alternative?

Comment: Is that the entirety of that module? If so why is it a module instead of a resource? It doesn't actually do anything other than add an unnecessary level of abstraction.

Comment: The `rds_event_sns.arn` is subsequently used in a few places inside the same tf file. I do not own these code and just want to make some minor changes, so I am not looking forward to do any refactoring.

Comment: Yes but you could replace where it has `module.rds_event_sns.arn` with `aws_sns_topic.rds_event.arn`. And the answer to your question is no which is why you will need to refactor this part at least. In general modules should be used for collecting multiple resources and making sensible decisions for the end user much like a class or module in a normal language. Don't abstract things before you need that abstraction.

Comment: Well, this class does a bit more than a simple wrapper. I just want to come up with a simpler example, so I left out some properties.

Comment: Fair enough. Unfortunately you can't just extend a module's resource like that. You could edit the module to make some of the parameters conditional and you can wrap a module in another module to add extra resources/change defaults etc but that's about the limit of things.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the response. If you convert the comment to an answer I am happy to accept it. Cheers